# Swagger openapi: Filter methods in openapi.yaml/ swagger-ui

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, openapi, swagger-2.0

I have upgraded my Jersey REST Service documentation to swagger openapi v3.

Now I want to introduce a filtering of methods by user authorization, so that only specific API methods show up in the swagger-ui/ openapi.yaml document.
The closest I came to is using a filter class ApiAuthorizationFilterImpl which extends io.swagger.v3.core.filter.AbstractSpecFilter.

```
public class ApiAuthorizationFilterImpl extends AbstractSpecFilter {
    
    @Override
    public Optional<Operation> filterOperation(
            Operation operation,
            ApiDescription api,
            Map<String, List<String>> params,
            Map<String, String> cookies,
            Map<String, List<String>> headers) {

            System.out.println("Operation filter is being executed");
            return Optional.of(operation);
}
```

I have added the filter as I am used from jersey filter classes, into the web.xml.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>io.swagger.v3.jaxrs2.integration.resources</param-value>
    </init-param>    
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
      <param-value>com.mapchart.core.ws.swagger.ApiAuthorizationFilterImpl</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
```

After that didn't seem to execute the filter, I was adding it into the openapi.yaml, as described [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Integration-and-configuration#configuration-properties):

```
prettyPrint: true
cacheTTL: 0
filterClass: ApiAuthorizationFilterImpl
openAPI:
  info:
    version: '1.0.0'
    title: 'OpenAPI documentation'
  servers:
    - url: '/my-rest-service'
```

Since this doesn't seem to execute the filter either, I wonder how it would actually be possible to add a filtering of openapi methods to show up in the openapi.yaml/ swagger-ui (with AbstractSpecFilter or another way)?

Answer (score 0):

The filterClass has to be specified as a fully-qualified class name to be executed, as I found out here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68482434/3271380

Additionally, I had to add some workarounds to make the filter work for user authentication:

- Add a custom parameter to the @Operation method, in my case I used SecurityRequirement with a custom value (using the hidden parameter or @Hidden annotation did not work, since Swagger will filter out those methods staticly earlier to executing this filter already)
- Add a custom header about the user type in a ContainerRequestFilter that gets executed previous to executing this filter. That way, that header can be retrieved in the ApiAuthorizationFilterImpl class.