# Swagger 2.x filter not executed

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, swagger-2.0

I am documenting an API with Swagger 2.x/ OpenAPI 3.0 (io.swagger.v3.oas.*) in a Jersey 2.34 web service.
I have extended io.swagger.v3.core.filter.SpecFilter to implement a custom filtering of Operations (methods) to show in the API docs.

```
import io.swagger.v3.core.filter.OpenAPISpecFilter;
import io.swagger.v3.core.filter.SpecFilter;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.Operation;

public class ApiAuthorizationFilterImpl extends SpecFilter {

@Override
protected Operation filterOperation(OpenAPISpecFilter filter, Operation operation, String resourcePath, String key, Map<String, List<String>> params, Map<String, String> cookies, Map<String, List<String>> headers) {
    System.out.println("Filtering operations: "+operation.getSummary());
}
```

Now, I am not able to get this filter working. When adding a filter expression in my web.xml,

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>ApiAuthorizationFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>my.package.ApiAuthorizationFilterImpl</filter-class>
</filter>
    
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>ApiAuthorizationFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

the service does not start but fails with

```
06-Jul-2021 13:01:36.592 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-27] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Exception starting filter [ApiAuthorizationFilter]
        java.lang.ClassCastException: class my.package.ApiAuthorizationFilterImpl cannot be cast to class javax.servlet.Filter (my.package.ApiAuthorizationFilterImpl is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @395fdbf6; javax.servlet.Filter is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @1ab3a8c8)
```

When adding the filter to jersey.config.server.provider.classnames, as done with other filters, it just does not seem to get picked up.

```
<servlet>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
      <param-value>my.package.ApiAuthorizationFilterImpl;</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

I wasn't really able to find the way to go, even though there are samples out there with different approaches.
What would be the correct way to get this filter executed or alternatively another approach to implement this filtering?

Answer (score 0):

Since I could figure this out now, I will post it here as an answer.

As I realized by diving a bit into the Swagger/ OpenAPI source code, this filter should be written as

```
import io.swagger.v3.core.filter.AbstractSpecFilter;
import io.swagger.v3.core.model.ApiDescription;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.Operation;

public class ApiAuthorizationFilterImpl extends AbstractSpecFilter {
    @Override
    public Optional<Operation> filterOperation(Operation operation, ApiDescription api, Map<String, List<String>> params, Map<String, String> cookies, Map<String, List<String>> headers) {
   }
}
```

It will then get executed by adding it into the openapi.yaml document as a filterClass

```
prettyPrint: true
cacheTTL: 0
readAllResources: false
filterClass: my.package.ApiAuthorizationFilterImpl 
openAPI:
  info:
...
```